# What is the dollar symbol used for in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this might be a newbie question, but every-time i see code like this:

```
var table = $("table[title='Refresh']");
```

And also code like this:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
```

i always sort of glaze over the `$` symbol .  It's a type of placeholder? or does it signify that its dynamic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a JavaScript function, most likely jQuery. Many JS frameworks define $ as a root selector function, jQuery being the most famous/used of those.

It has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: @Adel - Also, a tidbit - in JavaScript, `$` and `_` are valid characters for use in variable and function names, even on their own, which is exactly what it is in your question. In other words, `$()` is as valid a function name as `foo()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` is not related to ASP.NET in particular, but rather to the possible use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) which both use the `$` as an alias for a function. In the case of jQuery, `$` is just a shortcut for not having to write jQuery as in the following example:

```
jQuery('selector').datepicker()
```

Is the same as writing

```
$('selector').datepicker()
```

jQuery provides the [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method precisely to avoid conflicts with any other Javascript framework that may use the same `$` alias.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't part of ASP.NET, it's actually part of the JQuery library, which is a JavaScript library used for client side processing.

http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's the Shortcut / Alias to use in jQuery. Can be replaced with "jQuery " keyword."

Answer (score 1):

This is jquery syntax of using $ symbol. Read more here http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Answer (score 1):

That is JavaScript code.  In JavaScript, `$` is a legal name for a function or variable.  It just means that someone defined a function with that name.  You could define one yourself simply enough:

```
function $(){return "hello world";}
```

Then `$()` would print `"hello world"`.

Most famously, JQuery uses it as their selector function, in which it is used to query the page's DOM in a more powerful syntax than JavaScript's built in DOM querying methods, but there's nothing that guarantees that `$` is JQuery's usage, it could be anything.  (Note that I highly discourage you from actually defining `$` yourself and using it as a function, as virtually all JS developers have learned to read it as the JQuery's implementation.)